# Custom X-Axis labels in Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Timeline chart with x-axis having numbers instead of Date objects. To get the chart working, I am converting the numbers to Date objects like Date(num). However, X-axis labels display these numbers as Date string, instead of a number. I tried to find if the chart contains an option to set xaxis ticks, but unfortunately it does not have it.

How to set custom X-Axis labels (numbers in my case) in Google Timeline Chart? If that is not possible, how can I hide row labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not aware of any options that will allow you to customize the x-axis labels, in any fashion.

however, it is possible to remove the x-axis labels, after the chart has been drawn, on the chart's `'ready'` event.

see following working snippet...

once the `'ready'` event is fired...
first, find the outer `<rect>` element of the timeline.
next, find all of the `<text>` elements.
then check the `Y` attribute of each label,
if it is outside of the outer rect element's coordinates (`Y` + `height`),
it must be a x-axis label, and we can remove it (or make it transparent)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Row'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Bar'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});

  var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();  // keep example current
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Row 1', 'A-1', new Date(currentYear, 0, 1), new Date(currentYear, 2, 31)],
    ['Row 1', 'A-2', new Date(currentYear, 3, 1), new Date(currentYear, 5, 30)],
    ['Row 2', 'B-1', new Date(currentYear, 6, 1), new Date(currentYear, 8, 31)],
    ['Row 2', 'B-2', new Date(currentYear, 9, 1), new Date(currentYear, 11, 31)]
  ]);

  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // find outer <rect> element for timeline
    var outerRect = null;
    var rects = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    if (rects.length > 0) {
      rects = rects[0].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    }
    if (rects.length > 0) {
      outerRect = rects[rects.length - 1];
    }
    
    // find haxis labels
    if (outerRect !== null) {
      // find chart labels
      var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
      
      // loop backwards since we will be removing the elements
      for (var i = labels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // determine if haxis label (Y attribute is outside of outer rect element)
        rectBottom = parseFloat(outerRect.getAttribute('y')) + parseFloat(outerRect.getAttribute('height'));
        labelY = parseFloat(labels[i].getAttribute('y'));
        if (labelY > rectBottom) {
          // remove label
          labels[i].remove();

          // *** OR ***
          // make label transparent
          // labels[i].setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
        }
      }
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  drawChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, you could also change the content of the label and make it a number. but we cannot be sure how many labels there will be...